# Play Storyboard when image source changing

Tags: wpf, storyboard

How to begin a storyboard when a property binding changed ?

The source of my image change every 5s (in my ViewModel), and I want play a storyboard when the image is changing.

```
<Grid>
   <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding CurrentImage}"/>       
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would typically add an EventTrigger for an event that gets fired whenever the `Source` property changes. Unfortunately the Image control does not define such an event, so you would have to create your own by deriving from Image:

```
public class MyImage : Image
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SourceChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "SourceChanged", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyImage));

    static MyImage()
    {
        Image.SourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SourcePropertyChanged));
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler SourceChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(SourceChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SourceChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    private static void SourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = obj as Image;
        if (image != null)
        {
            image.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SourceChangedEvent));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could use the `SourceChanged` event in an EventTrigger:

```
<local:MyImage Source="{Binding Image}">
    <local:MyImage.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyImage.SourceChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    ...
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </local:MyImage.Triggers>
</local:MyImage>
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better add an event to your ViewModel and launch it whenever the source changes. And, of course, use an EventTrigger on that event to execute your Storyboard.